# Issue with .hover and .on with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue using `.hover` and `.on` to produce a change using jQuery.

I've included a [jsfiddle with the code](https://jsfiddle.net/af291602/g96tcbpw/1/):

```
$(".nName").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'color': "blue", "text-decoration": "underline"});
},
function() {
    $(this).css('color', "black");
});
```

Comment: You closed your hover function right after the first line of code. Did you intend to do this? ```$(this).css({'color': "blue", "text-decoration": "underline"});} <----```

Comment: @tomerpacific I believe it is, because after it hes added `,function() {$(this).css('color', "black");});` so the first apply on hover and the second on leave.

Comment: Yeah, @tomerpacific I thought appropriate syntex was: 
   $(".selector").hover(function () {
    //stuff to do on mouse enter
}, 
function () {
    //stuff to do on mouse leave
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".nName").hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'color': "blue",
    "text-decoration": "underline"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).css('color', "black");
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').append('<div class="nName2">Dynamically rendered node1</div>')
  // The hover event will take effect here.
  /**
  $(".nName2").hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'color': "blue",
    "text-decoration": "underline"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).css('color', "black");
});
**/
}, 2000)

$(".nName2").hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'color': "blue",
    "text-decoration": "underline"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).css('color', "black");
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').append('<div class="nName3">Dynamically rendered node2</div>')

}, 2000)

$('body').on('mouseenter', '.nName3', function() {
  $(this).css({
    'color': "blue",
    "text-decoration": "underline"
  });
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.nName3', function() {
  $(this).css('color', "black");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nName">Existing node</div>
```

Unable to bind hover event to dynamically rendered node when page is initialized.

In other way, you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `hover`.

Comment: Please consider leaving an explanation on why your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your fiddle is that you are trying to attach an event on a dynamic rendered element.

If you apply an event on some element it should be present in the DOM.

In your case, you need to bind your event to the `document` and then its child.

Please rewrite your jquery like this

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).css({
      'color': "blue",
      "text-decoration": "underline"
    });
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).css('color', "black");
  }
}, ".nName");

$(document).on('click', '.nName', function () {
  $(".individualStream").empty();
  var specificName = $(this).text();
  var specificUser = streams.user.specificName;

  for (var i = 0; i < specificUser.length; i++) {
    var tweet = specificUser[i].message;
    var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
    var $name = $('<span class="nName"></span>');
    var $time = $('<div class="time"></div>');
    var $at = $('<span class="at"></span>');
    $time.text("Time of Tweet: " + tweet.created_at);
    $name.text(specificName);
    $at.text('@');
    $tweet.text(" " + tweet);
    $tweet.prepend($name);
    $tweet.prepend($at);
    $tweet.append($time);
    $tweet.prependTo($(".inidvidualStream"));
    $('.twitterStream').hide();
    $('.individualStream').show();
  }
});
```

I am using a mouseenter and mouseleave event here because we can not use same syntax like `hover` in case of dynamic rendered element.